# What intent extra to make youtube android app automatically close when reach the end of video

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, youtube-api

What parameter should I put on intent to start vnd.youtube to make it close the activity when it reach the end of video. In Youtube API it's something like this:

```
YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(getApplicationContext(), mVideoId, true, true);
```

I want to know the equivalent for "finishOnEnd" option for starting youtube activity directly like following:

```
Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + mVideoId));
                        viewIntent.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
                        viewIntent.putExtra("force_finishOnEnd", true);
                        startActivity(viewIntent);
```

I found the equivalent for "fullscreen" is "force_fullscreen", but how about "finishOnEnd" option?

Thanks.

Comment: depends on the API. you can use `canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions(Context context)` to find whether it is supported or not.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: Thanks for the answer, yes it's supported. But I still want to know what key should I put in the viewIntent.putExtra for finishOnEnd? thanks.

Comment: `intent = YouTubeIntents.createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions(this,mVideoId, true, true);
            startActivity(intent);` dont need to put any key. just use the above intent code to start an activity

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: What I want to get is the equivalent of that with `Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + mVideoId));
                        viewIntent.putExtra("force_fullscreen", true);
                        viewIntent.putExtra("force_finishOnEnd", true);
                        startActivity(viewIntent);`. For using the Youtube API directly, I have already use the method that you suggest, but what I want to know is the equivalent name for the extra parameter that I can put on above code ("force_finishOnEnd" <- this is not the real key name). thanks

Comment: why you intended to use that if Youtube provides a steadfast way to do this ? is there any specific requirement ?

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: Because the API can only be used for Youtube app version above 4.2.16, but not all user device already have their Youtube app updated. thanks.

Comment: thats exactly what `canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions` do, if options are not supported it will return `false`.

Comment: probably you haven't checked the [API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubeIntents#canResolvePlayVideoIntentWithOptions(android.content.Context))

Comment: @MurtazaHussain: I also knew that options and it's also return true for old Youtube app version (3.5.5). There are two ways to use the Youtube app in Android, by using the API or calling it using Intent. For old version of Youtube app, I need to use `Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:" + mVideoId));`, and so I still need to know what is the name of extra that I need to put in order to make the same effect like in the API, which is close the activity when it reached the end of the video. thanks.

Comment: app which do not support those options will not work AFAIK. Regards

Answer (score 6):

intent.putExtra("finish_on_ended", true);

Comment: Do you have any documentation regarding this?

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, until somebody forwarded me this:

[image: See source code]

So all the YouTube Library does is this:

```
 .putExtra("force_fullscreen", true).putExtra("finish_on_ended", true);
```